# Prevent macro expansion within setbox

Tags: boxes, expansion

Following code is the quintessence of a problem i'm facing:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newbox\boxa
\newbox\boxb
\newbox\boxc
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\setbox\boxc\hbox{Hello World!}

\def\foobar{MIST}

\setbox\boxa=\hbox{\foobar\space A}

\def\foobar{MOST}
\setbox\boxb=\hbox{\foobar\space B}

\setbox\boxc=\hbox{\unhbox\boxc\space \unhbox\boxa\space \unhbox\boxb.}

\unhbox\boxc
\end{document}
```

with the desired output being

```
Hello World! MOST A MOST B.
```

but i only get

```
Hello World! MIST A MOST B.
```

Is it technically possible to get the desired output by doing magic on  `\setbox\boxa` only?

Comment: no.............

Comment: only way is to define all kinds of boxes you need, and when defining `\boxc` use some conditional to `\unhbox` only those you want at that spot. but macros are expanded when the box is build and there is no undoing that or doing it again.

Comment: you can get what you need by saving macros, not by saving boxes. A box contains typeset text there is no tex control structure in a box at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i cannot measure the size of macro contents, can i?

Comment: Well, "It isn't possible by design" would be an answer i'd flag as solution...

Comment: macro contents do not have a size, they are just a list of tokens but at any point you can typeset them to a box and measure the result

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you need by saving macros, not by saving boxes.

A box contains typeset text: there is no tex control structure in a box at all, so getting the same text each time you use a box even if macros have changed is "by design".